# Google API Contacts query by Extended Property

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

I've uploader contacts from my application to Google Contacts with an external code property named extcod.

```
ExtendedProperty property = new ExtendedProperty();
property.Name = "http://www.example.com/schemas/2005#mycal.extcod";
property.Value = item["ana_id"].ToString();
newEntry.ExtendedProperties.Add(property);
```

Now I'd like to search a Google Contacts by the extended property extcod. but I can't understand how to use `ContactsQuery` class to setting up a where condition that use `ExtendedProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the ContactsQuery's "Query" attribute:
  http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/feedquery.cs#361

This will be used as the "q=" query parameter which sends a fulltext query. The Google Contacts API v3 support fulltext query on every text fields which includes extended property.
Unfortunately, there is no way to send a query on extended property only.

Best,
Alain